# Raindrops are falling on my... glasses?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, random, animation

I live in the UK, where it rains. A lot. I also have the unfortunate necessity to need to wear glasses to see, which means that when it rains (as it is now), I can barely see out of them. This challenge is so that you can all experience the same!

### Task

Output ASCII art glasses with a drop of water added each second.

### Input

None

### Output

A pair of glasses with drops of water on them.

#### Glasses

```
 ________________________
|          /__\          |
|         /    \         |
|        /      \        |
\_______/        \_______/
```

#### Raindrops

A raindrop is denoted by a `.`. A raindrop is randomly placed on the glasses' lenses. So when a raindrop is placed, the glasses might look like this

```
 ________________________
|          /__\          |
|    .    /    \         |
|        /      \        |
\_______/        \_______/
```

If it is placed on a blank space (), an `.` is placed on the image. If it is placed on a square which already has a raindrop, the drop graduates.

The steps on drops are

- no drops placed:
- 1 drop placed: `.`
- 2 drops placed: `o`
- 3 drops placed: `O`
- 4+ drops placed: `@`

### Rules

- The image should **look** as though it stays in place. This means that you can either clear the screen or print enough newlines to "clear" the screen. You cannot return a list of steps. Sorry about this, but you should be able to work around that.
- When outputting newlines to "clear" the screen, you must have at least 3 newlines between the glasses.
- The code runs until the glasses are full of fully graduated drops i.e. until the output looks like this:

```
     ________________________
    |@@@@@@@@@@/__\@@@@@@@@@@|
    |@@@@@@@@@/    \@@@@@@@@@|
    |@@@@@@@@/      \@@@@@@@@|
    \_______/        \_______/
```

- Shortest code in *bytes* wins.

Comment: "_The code runs until the glasses are full of fully graduated drops_" Perhaps specify an approximate sleep/wait time? Like 150 or 250 ms?

Comment: Does the code have to stop when the glasses look like the final output or can it keep running but just not affect anything?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I would imagine until the glasses are full, as written in the spec :v

Comment: Droplet's random fall does have to fall randomly on lenses even on part of the bits of the lens that are `@`, right?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder it should terminate after all have graduated

Comment: @KevinCruijssen sleep time can be anything above or equal to 1ms

Comment: @RandomUser Okay and `sleep time doesn't matter` does this mean you don't need to sleep at all?

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>269</s> <s>267</s> 265 bytes

```js
document.write('<pre id=o>')
a=[...` _8_8_8
| 9 /__\\  9|
| 9/ 4\\ 9|
| 8/ 6\\ 8|
\\_7/ 8\\_7/`.replace(/.\d/g,s=>s[0].repeat(s[1]))]
s=" .oO@@"
g=_=>o.innerHTML=a.join``
f=(i=s.indexOf(a[j=Math.random()*a.length|0])+1)=>i?g(a[j]=s[i]):f()
g()
setInterval(f,1e3)
```

Edit: Saved <s>2</s> 4 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.

Comment: something goes wrong at the upper left corner

Comment: -1 because it's bugged (see Jenny's comment)

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Sorry about that, I got bitten by a "feature" of Firefox's clipboard... should be OK now.

Comment: Save a couple of bytes with `innerText` instead of `textContent` and `search` instead of `indexOf`. And a few more by just using `<pre id=o` as HTML, rather than `document.write`ing it.

Comment: @Shaggy But that would make it `HTML/JS`, and I wanted this to be a "pure" JS solution.

Comment: @Shaggy Also, `search` will fail on a ``\``...

Comment: (I used `innerHTML` because Firefox only recently implemented `innerText`.)

Comment: Would `f=(i=s.indexOf(a[j=Math.random()*a.length|0])+1)=>i?g(a[j]=s[i]):f()` work, for a 2 byte saving?

Comment: @Shaggy Great find, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>449</s> <s>421</s> 420 bytes

```java
v->{String q="########",g=" ________________________\n|##"+q+"/__\\##"+q+"|\n|#"+q+"/    \\#"+q+"|\n|"+q+"/      \\"+q+"|\n\\_______/        \\_______/\n\n\n";for(int t=0,n,x;g.matches("(?s).*[#\\.oO].*");Thread.sleep(150)){for(;(x=g.charAt(n=(int)(Math.random()*g.length())))!=35&x!=46&x!=111&x!=79;);g=t++>0?g.substring(0,n)+(x<36?".":x<47?"o":x<80?"@":"O")+g.substring(n+1):g;System.out.println(g.replace('#',' '));}}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##dZJbT8IwFIDf/RXHkkjLsEJEUGqdPvgIPpj44owpY3TT0c614Azw27GFeUmMp0kv3zltun19EUtxrItEvUxft3EujIGRyNTqACBTNilnIk5g7JcAS51NIcYPflgSsGmp3w3cVnFS2Ewr5oo2B64zVtgshjEo4LBdHl@t7m2ZKQlvHDXqQG3JETz/E5Fau5LgLUAnbhHV87XHe@qv4/g3/qGef@Eoqs@rMz73RVzWNcRmusTuS8HyTlu1KybpXNg4TQxGODSEth4bUUT13RNtIcLIytczXHFJ41SUNxYr7vcTPBI2paVQUz3HpCVpnihpU0xcHPLTs6PqkPf6vu92u34YXDDCJLdBcNUJJTWLidn9JezuQQJcXZ72Q0TRsLrsDUKk/eS8E6JrNER3iAS/d6igS4aS3X8Ym8ypXlhaOG5zhSUtkyJ3DnGz0Ww3oUkI22y2zGsqFpPcaapt7eTOnXq8l/X4BOKv4/1DUDTGapHnZK98s/0E) (`Thread.sleep` is removed so you instantly see the result.)

```java
v->(){                      // Method without empty unused parameter and no return-type
  String q="########",g=" ________________________\n|##"+q+"/__\\##"+q+"|\n|#"+q+"/    \\#"+q+"|\n|"+q+"/      \\"+q+"|\n\\_______/        \\_______/\n\n\n";
                            //  The glasses (with inner spaces replaced by '#')
  for(int t=0,n,x;          //  Index integers
      g.matches("(?s).*[#\\.oO].*");
                            //   Loop (1) as long as the glasses still contain "#.oO"
      Thread.sleep(150)){   //   And sleep 150ms after each iteration to give the animation
    for(;                   //   Inner loop (2)
         (x=g.charAt(n=(int)(Math.random()*g.length())))!=35&x!=46&x!=111&x!=79;
                            //    To find the next '#', '.', 'o' or 'O' randomly
    );                      //   End of inner loop (2)
    g=t++>0??               //   Flag so it prints the initial glasses without a raindrop
      g.substring(0,n)+(x<36?".":x<47?"o":x<80?"@":"O")+g.substring(n+1):g;
                            //    Add a raindrop on this random position
    System.out.println(g    //   And print the glasses
        .replace('#',' ')); //   After we've replaced '#' with spaces
  }                         //  End of loop (1)
}                           // End of method
```

**Output:**

NOTE: The dots are a bit weird in the gif, but that's a problem in my ScreenToGif.exe..
[image]

Comment: You know what is dazzling me about, those weird dots (same applies to scaled-down `"`) really look like there is a real water drop on top of my screen

Comment: This does not account for the possibility of a drop falling on an @ :v

Comment: @Jenkar that is the second time you have said that on answers. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: @RandomUser Basicly, the current code in this answer looks for a spot that is not yet an @ to fall on, rather than falling on the lenses randomly, even if it is an at. The "4+" in requirements seems to indicate that this is not the case to go, but instead one should fall on the lens randomly, including an @. Is this not the correct interpretation?

Comment: @Jenkar It doesn't matter *how* it does it, just that it does it without violating any rules or standard loopholes. I never said "It must have a uniform random distribution" in the question so this answer is fine.

Comment: @Jenkar Hmm you're indeed right. Missed the `4+` part. But I guess _RandomUser_ thinks it's fine like this. Personally I think it's better this way, otherwise it might take a very long time before the entire glasses are filled near the end. But well-spotted, nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

## F#, non-recursive <s>379</s> <s>414</s> 404 bytes

```fs
open System
let z=String.replicate
let mutable s,d=z 54" ",new Random()
while Seq.exists((<>)'@')s do printfn" %s\n|%s/__\\%s|\n|%s/    \\%s|\n|%s/%7s%s|\n\\_______/%9s_______/\n\n"(z 24"_")(s.[..9])(s.[10..19])(s.[20..28])(s.[29..37])(s.[38..45])"\\"(s.[46..53])"\\";Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);d.Next54|>fun i->s<-(s.[i]|>function|' '->"."|'.'->"o"|'o'->"O"|_->"@")|>(fun c->s.Remove(i,1).Insert(i,c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc9Rb4IwEAfwdz9F04RAEzlBYWpU4utetkT2NgxhcM4m0DJapzN8d1bAJbuX/v7X3CV3Um4lhew6WaMg8Y/SWE1K1OS@i3XDxSc0WJc8zzQO7eqis48SiZoWuzsJA0roVOCVHDJRyMphk@uZm@8YvwBvXGnlONuI2XubKVJIUpuV@iQosVQiWkvN0jRJLNWOgZj6F62lGpwk6Vgza63@aNqCOncyD2hKmaPgHWB9HOB7AP7Dc@P56uE1wGI5erECCMIjo0lC@xw8AYSLMW/ezg1mRX/8KIhLxNrxPc9jmwJe8KbDoI1OF0G4G6mt22/gx6GTay5FaxPbjSjQ1oYe0kD2eKVtap49ZW3k9PO5mYcDVvIbHT71GTwLhY02zhnrul8)

- -7 bytes thanks to @vzwick

  - by aliasing String.replicate
  - by opening System instead of referencing it every time
- -3 bytes by reducing the while loop to one line

I love the premise of this challenge :)

And thanks for the earworm.

## F#, <s>406</s> <s>441</s> <s>438</s> <s>437</s> 423 bytes

```fs
open System
let z=String.replicate
let s,d=z 54" ",new Random()
let rec(!)s=s="";printfn" %s\n|%s/__\\%s|\n|%s/    \\%s|\n|%s/%7s%s|\n\\_______/%9s_______/\n\n"(z 24"_")(s.[..9])(s.[10..19])(s.[20..28])(s.[29..37])(s.[38..45])"\\"(s.[46..53])"\\";Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);if Seq.exists((<>)'@')s then d.Next 54|>fun i-> !((s.[i]|>function|' '->"."|'.'->"o"|'o'->"O"|_->"@")|>(fun c->s.Remove(i,1).Insert(i,c)))else()
!s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdBRa4MwEAfw932KNCAmUK/a2rWlU/q6lw3m3maRoucqaHRetnXF7@6idrB7ye9/4QK5nJyqVnXf1w0qFv2QxuquRM2uQaTbQr1Di01ZpCeNY5vmWXBla58zPlf4zV5OKqsrIcfLFlMxkxRQwPm@MdM6V5xZFKvOokWSxLFF3RSYqX/R2tDoOE6mWlg7@qNpKy6ubOnzhEtB8AawO47wXADv5qXxcnvzDmC1mbzaAvjro@RxzIfs3wOsV1Pev55bPGXDPydBVCI2wnNdV@6LnEX4AXgpSJMQD6G0D7Ykps9mVxk84UWbVXRh/qlY4YRsJob3i@PYSXVRq85mthNy4J0NA2qDesAz7xJzHLjsQjHMp05I8IJV/YWimHsSHhVhq41TKSWWhGbJM@r7Xw)

- -3 bytes by constraining s to string by comparing it with string
- -1 byte, function name is now "!" saving a single space when calling it
- -7 bytes thanks to @vzwick

  - by aliasing String.replicate
  - by opening System instead of referencing it every time
- -1 byte, no need for parenthesis when calling d.Next
- -6 bytes, function is now one line

## Explanation

```fs
open System
let z = String.replicate    // define alias
let s, d = z 54 " ", new Random() // s holds a flat representation of the glasses.. glasses
let rec(!) s =
    s=""; // type s to string
    printfn" %s\n|%s/__\\%s|\n|%s/    \\%s|\n|%s/%7s%s|\n\\_______/%9s_______/\n\n"
        (z 24 "_")     // top of the glasses
        (s.[..9])      // slice
        (s.[10..19])   // and
        (s.[20..28])   // dice
        (s.[29..37])   // the
        (s.[38..45])   // glasses
        "\\"           // \ gets prepended with 6 spaces thanks to %7s
        (s.[46..53])
        "\\";          // same deal, just 8 spaces this time
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if Seq.exists((<>)'@') s then // if not everything's totally covered
        d.Next 54                 // get new random int < 54 (string has indices 0-53)
        |> fun i->                // passing is shorter than a let binding, saves two spaces and a new line
            !(                    // call the function again with new drop on glasses
              (s.[i]              // get part of the glasses drop fell on
              |>function
              |' '->"."           // promote drop
              |'.'->"o"
              |'o'->"O"
              |_->"@")
              |>(fun c-> s.Remove(i,1).Insert(i,c))) // and insert this in the string
    else ()
!s
```

Comment: You can save 1 char by `open System` and removing `System` from the `Random()` and `Threading.Thread.Sleep()` calls ;)

Comment: A few more characters shaved: https://tio.run/##TZDfa4NADMff/SvCgXgHbaqtri2d0te9bFD3NosUjaugZ@fdtq74v7tTO1gg5PPND0JSqHndyKbvmwtJiH@UptqqSMMtjHVbynds6VKV2UnTmFazPLxB4DNgM0nfcDjJvKm5GIstZdCCCi3jjO0uZl4XkoGtEtnZapGmSWKrbhJg7J@012rkJEknW9hb9YcmLRm/wdJnKRNc4Rvi9jiC5yJ6d14aXm7uvEVcrSdebRD94ChYkrBB@w@IwWrSu9dzS6d8uHQijCuiC/dc1xUWlAXE9IF0LZVWnD9Gwtk7QoE@k7QAhqvLMMdnumoe@GYAhgXlsYuKT5npspGdA848Ysg6BwdoDDQDvLAuNWHPRBdx0w3ZPFJ4oLr5Il7OPIFPUlGrDWfC9LQWUKXI/Nr8uO9/AQ

Comment: @vzwick thanks :) found another few bytes as I was editig

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>365</s> 328 bytes

That's a bit better...

```python
import time,random
g=' '+'_'*24+r"""
|xxX/__\Xxx|
|xX/    \Xx|
|X/      \X|
\_______/        \_______/""".replace('X','x'*8)
while 1:
 print'\n'*3+g.replace('x',' ')
 s='x.oO@@'
 if all(c not in g for c in s[:-2]):exit()
 i,c=random.choice([(i,s[s.index(j)+1])for i,j in enumerate(g)if j in s])
 g=g[:i]+c+g[i+1:]
 time.sleep(1)
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/IPuU/2)

The above link uses 30 lines instead of 3, but you can see it with 3 if you resize your browser window to be small enough vertically. Change `time.sleep(1)` to `time.sleep(.1)` for 10x speed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <strike>237</strike> <strike>224</strike> <strike>228</strike> <strike>218</strike> <strike>206</strike> <strike>198</strike> 197 bytes

```ruby
g=" #{?_*24}
|x##/__ax##|
|x#/    ax#|
|x/      ax|
a#{u=?_*7}/xa#{u}/


".gsub ?x,?#*8;217.times{|t|puts g.tr('#a',' \\');()while t<216&&g[x=rand*106]!~/[#.oO]/;g[x]=g[x].tr '#.oO','.oO@';sleep 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#HYzRCoIwGIXv9xTLgVMx1yQ0MLE36AFUZNlQwVR0kuDsrbu2rf/i/Oc7cM5exQZEa1I4/nkDckGIFAVTT2ogUJ0iDX@vSQKG1jlWlXAji/YbAQAYXjXND5gsboKcS@TT0BPNi0@rFHKYxQQrT4wWRgy7GGYZtiPLftdNy6G4@jQwzSpd4pF1T4eegvzwISny@ntOIpXnsRbVh1iHakHpDUdTy/kA6bbv364/lqys@Q8)

<strike>Previous answer was wrong, it did not take into account a raindrop falling on a @.</strike> Apparently not a requirement. Some bytes saved.

This terminates with an error thrown, but this definitely terminates as soon as the full glasses are printed.

- Saved 13 bytes by <strike>putting the printing into a lambda, and</strike> changing the assignment to use tr (duh)
- 8 bytes loss with the 1 second requirement.
- 10 bytes gain by using the gsub trick instead of interpolation (seen & adapted from [mbomb007's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122284/raindrops-are-falling-on-my-glasses/122557#122557)).
- 12 bytes gain by removing the lambda printing now that the print is written only once >.>
- 1 byte gain by making all the `\\` be `a`, then changing back inside the tr
- 7 byte gain by putting the changing the spaces on the last line with another `x` (duh). In case some of you guys are wondering why this doesn't affect the main loop : the main loop doesn't consider the last line to determine its `x`.
- 1 byte gain by removing the  at the end of the top of the glasses

Yay < 200 bytes :D

Gif :

[image: Gif]

Comment: For future reference you can edit your previous answer to one that works instead of deleting it and adding a new one.

Comment: Could you add in a gif of this running?

Comment: @RandomUser Done.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>313</s> <s>309</s> <s>305</s> 304 bytes

Needs to be golfed down quite a bit;

```
c;f(r,q){for(char*m=" ________________________\n|**********/__\\**********|\n|*********/    \\*********|\n|********/      \\********|\n\\_______/        \\_______/\n";c<216;r=rand()%144,m-=135)for(system("clear");*m++;putchar(*m^42?*m:32))q=--r?*m:*m^42?*m^46?*m^111?*m^79?*m:64:79:111:46,c+=q!=*m,*m=q;}
```

I run it with the following test stub

```
main()
{
    srand(time(0));    
    f();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 438 bytes

```
f=Flatten;p=Print;z=32;q=95;l=124;t=Table;v=z~t~8;s={f@{z,q~t~24,z},f@{124,z~t~10,47,q,q,92,z~t~10,l},f@{l,z~t~9,47,z~t~4,92,z~t~9,l},f@{l,v,47,z~t~6,92,v,l},f@{92,q~t~7,47,v,92,q~t~7,47}};c=0;Monitor[While[c<54,a=s[[i=RandomInteger@{2,4},j=RandomChoice[Range[2,13-i]~Join~Range[14+i,25]]]];If[a==z,s[[i,j]]=46,If[a==46,s[[i,j]]=111,If[a==111,s[[i,j]]=48,If[a==48,s[[i,j]]=64]]]];c=Count[Flatten@s,64];Pause@1],Column@FromCharacterCode@s]
```

here is a 10x speed result gif

[image]

Comment: Never used Mathematica but could you assign to `Table`, `95` and `32`?

Comment: As in `t=Table` `x = 32` and `y = 95`?

Comment: yes of course. I golfed it a lot since yesterday

Comment: You might be able to remove 6 bytes by replacing the last `Flatten` with `f`?

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>576</s> <s>510</s> <s>429</s> 416 Bytes

```
j()(IFS=
printf "$*")
for i in {53..0};{ a[$i]= 
b[$i]=@;}
while(($i == 0));do clear
echo  " ________________________
|`j ${a[@]::10}`/__\\`j ${a[@]:10:10}`|
|`j ${a[@]:20:9}`/    \\`j ${a[@]:29:9}`|
|`j ${a[@]:38:8}`/      \\`j ${a[@]:46}`|
\_______/        \_______/"
[ `j ${a[@]}` = `j ${b[@]}` ]&&{
i=1
}
sleep 1
d=`shuf -i0-53 -n1`
c=${a[$d]}
case $c in  )a[$d]=.;;.)a[$d]=o;;o)a[$d]=0;;0)a[$d]=@;esac
done
```

Wow, golfed a lot. If anyone have any idea for further golfing, I'm open to suggestions

[Try it yourself!](https://tio.run/##ddDBaoNAEAbg@zzFYJegBe0am5K4LHgq9NyjEV11xQ2iQVt6MAu99EX7IlaNaZND5/TPz8eyTCq6chgOpmW@PL9yOLaqfivQIPeGBUXTokJVY7/xHIdq1qMIiYr49@cXpHMKmIaPUlXSNIlCzpFaFssbzCopWpBZ2SAaGP8zcEoOSHoRBpHvu1QnD3G83/91Lp3b07VbU383Qhznmq53U30jva2/XeStfXya5H75xAJGcikMCPFX6wT5eUvPW7Ra9aC4CxruukrKI7qQ86Qr3wu0FbU3Htq1m0DGpwdIHmnIRCeRZNMpx9NZc8sdxpwlNow1S6SM0SUGTHYig7yp5TD8AA) It has the sleep commented because of the 60 seconds limit

Here is the gif:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 167 bytes

**Note that `\x1b` is a literal escape character.**

```pl
$_="\x1bc 24_
|10X/__\\10X|
|9X/4 \\9X|
|8X/6 \\8X|
\\7_/8 \\7_/
";s/\d+(.)/$1x$&/ge;do{$a[rand 54]++,sleep print s/X/($",".",o,O)[$a[$-++%54]]||"@"/ger}while grep$_<4,@a
```

[See it online!](https://asciinema.org/a/90ybDoChlx5kaznCUGTHKv5ZY)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>262</s> 254 bytes

```php
for($t=" 8_8_8_
|Y9Y/__\Y9Y|
|9Y/4 \9Y|
|8Y/6 \8Y|
\\7_/8 \\7_/";$c=$t[$i++];)$s.=$c<1?$c:str_repeat($t[$i++],$c);for(;$c=$s[++$k];)$c!=Y?:$s[$m[]=$k]=" ";for(;$u<216;print str_pad($s,999,"
",sleep(1)))$u+=($c=".oO@"[$a[$p=rand(0,53)]++])&&$s[$m[$p]]=$c;
```

Run with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea6ce8dcc4729cf3bc0781abd2e2cf9c6b085891).

**breakdown**

```php
# prep 1: generate template from packed string
for($t=" 8_8_8_\n|Y9Y/__\Y9Y|\n|9Y/4 \9Y|\n|8Y/6 \8Y|\n\\7_/8 \\7_/";
    $c=$t[$i++];)$s.=$c<1?$c:str_repeat($t[$i++],$c);
# prep 2: map substituted spaces and replace with real spaces
for(;$c=$s[++$k];)$c!=Y?:$s[$m[]=$k]=" ";
# loop until glasses are fully wet:
for(;$u<216;
    # 4. print glasses prepended with 865 newlines
    print str_pad($s,999,"\n",
    # 3. wait 1 second
        sleep(1)))
    $u+=($c=".oO@"[
        $a[$p=rand(0,53)    # 1. pick random position
        ]++])               # 2. and increment
        &&$s[$m[$p]]=$c         # if not fully wet, graduate drop
    ;                           # and increment drop count ($u+=)
```